# How to correctly return comment from my controller and use it in the .done() AJAX function?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

How can I return the comment which was saved to the database in order to use it in the .done() function so I can display that comment without refreshing the page?

CommentController:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Comment;

class CommentsController extends Controller
{
    public function postComment(Request $request){
        $userId = $request['userId'];
        $imageId = $request['imageId'];
        $commentText = $request['comment'];

        $comment = new Comment();
        $comment->user_id = $userId;
        $comment->image_id = $imageId;
        $comment->comment = $commentText;
        $comment->save();
    }
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$('.postComment').on('click', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var userId = $("input[name=user_id]").val();
        var imageId = $("input[name=image_id]").val();
        var comment = $("textarea[name=comment]").val();

        $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            url: urlComment,
            data: {userId: userId, imageId: imageId, comment: comment, _token: token}
        }).done(function(serverResponseData){
            $("textarea[name=comment]").val("");
            $('.comments').append('<p></p>');
        })
    });
```

Comment: first add return in controller `return $commentText` and in this line add `serverResponseData` result `$('.comments').append('<p>'+serverResponseData+'</p>');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do this by return json resonse and access the data return in done method in ajax

```
 public function postComment(Request $request){
    $userId = $request['userId'];
    $imageId = $request['imageId'];
    $commentText = $request['comment'];

    $comment = new Comment();
    $comment->user_id = $userId;
    $comment->image_id = $imageId;
    $comment->comment = $commentText;
    $comment->save();
    return response()->json(['comment'=>$comment]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can return the comment and it will be on the serverResponseData
you just need to add it on the return of your method:

```
 public function postComment(Request $request){
    $userId = $request['userId'];
    $imageId = $request['imageId'];
    $commentText = $request['comment'];

    $comment = new Comment();
    $comment->user_id = $userId;
    $comment->image_id = $imageId;
    $comment->comment = $commentText;
    $comment->save();
    return $comment;
}
```

After that serverResponseData will hold the value, if you would like it to access it as if it was an array you could set the return type of the ajax to json : *dataType: 'json'*